# Issue with /cmd_vel Twist msg and Arduino

Tags: arduino, ros-noetic, geometry-msgs, rosserial-arduino

I have a laptop with ubuntu 20 and ROS noetic connected to an Arduino using rosserial_arduino.
The blink example from the ROS library works fine.
But I fail to set up a subscriber on my Arduino that listens to Twist commands from /cmd_vel. The issue occurs when i use `geometry_msgs::Twist` instead of `std_msgs::Empty`.
Every time my arduino gets a Twist command, the LED should blink.
But nothing happens.
Here is the code:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>

//Configure ROS
ros::NodeHandle nh;
geometry_msgs::Twist msg;

//Create a message callback that updates the motor speeds
void messageCb(const geometry_msgs::Twist& cmd_vel)
{
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH-digitalRead(5)); 
}

//Subscribe to the Twist message
ros::Subscriber <geometry_msgs::Twist> sub("/cmd_vel", &messageCb);

//Setup the node and subscriber once
void setup()
{
    nh.initNode();
    nh.subscribe(sub);
    pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
    Serial.begin(9600); // needs to be at end of setup loop
}

//Loop forever
void loop()
{
  while (!nh.connected())
  {
    nh.spinOnce();
  }
    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(1);
}
```

Im really glad for any hint!

Regards!

Comment: Your code looks fine. But are you sure that the below part should be at the end of the setup function? Why don't you try initialisation from the beginning. > Serial.begin(9600); Also did you check whether you were able to see cmd_vel topic in arudino? > rostopic echo /cmd_vel Would you mind sharing what type error you are getting?